# 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command in jenkins only

Tags: batch, batch-file, jenkins, npm

EDIT: if any one else will have this problem. The file was cmd, so calling `npm.cmd` fixed the problem.

I nee to preform :

```
npm run build
```

It's a part of a Jenkins deploy. 
I have created a batch file that preform all the npm actions. 
When I run the command or the batch file from CMD it run just fine, no meter the path a execute if from. But when I execute if from "Execute windows batch command" I get:

```
> npm run build:dev 
'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: As per my comment on Stackoverflow on this duplicate question, I suggest you [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321639/is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat)

Comment: Tnx, already did. Actually the reason was that the file was npm.cmd. 
Called it this way and it worked.

Comment: So then perhaps removing the question would be best.

Comment: Don't think so. I searched a lot, and this might help someone else.

Comment: What might help them? There is no valid answer to this, a question with no answer is no help...

Comment: But there is. 
From cmd I could call npm with no problem, direct of in batch script.
But in jenkins it failed with the error. Only when I called it `npm.cmd` it worked.

Comment: my point is, there is no answer to this question, the answer below is not really the solution that resolved your issue..was it?? So a question with no answer is not useful. unless the answer below solved the issue and it was marked as correct, then it might be useful.

Comment: I will edit me question or post an edit to the answer. 
And any way many times I have found the correct answer in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by tuning the command this way:
`npm.cmd run build`

Comment: I had the same idea, but didn't fix it for me

Comment: maybe you need to set the path to npm or add the full path to your script. 
Can you call npm directly in cmd?

Comment: I actually tried setting the full path, but then the next thing was that it indirectly wanted to invoke the "node" process and it couldn't find that neither. . Actually I found a solution and will post it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, next tried renaming it to `npm.cmd` which didn't work neither, then tried a full path, which worked at first. But next thing I knew, the npm script had dependencies to other processes which couldn't be found neither. It took me a while to realize what was going on, but it made perfect sense.

In windows, whenever you install a command line application it adds its installation folders to the `PATH` variable. And that is also the case for `node`, `npm`, `ng` and many more. There is a tricky thing with the `PATH` variable though, it doesn't just refresh for active terminals or processes. So, whenever you install something to it, you need to close and reopen your terminals.

And actually the same goes for your running jenkins. It also needs to be restarted in order to have its `PATH` variable updated.

So chances are that you just installed node or npm but you didn't restart your system yet, and didn't restart your jenkins server. In that case, it will give you exactly the error mentioned above.

All my issues were solved **simply by restarting the jenkins service**.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your NPM is not visible by Jenkins.
You can write the CMD command using the full path to npm.exe:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\node-v10.15.3-win-x86\node.exe run build
```

To see node version:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\node-v10.15.3-win-x86\node.exe -v
```